# IE8, Stack Overflow occurs when run a jQuery.sub after sorting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

IE8, Stack Overflow occurs when run a jQuery.sub after sorting elements.

Is this a bug of IE8?

Javascript:

```
jQuery('.wrapper').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    axis: "y",
    opacity: 0.5
});

jQuery('.wrapper').bind('sortupdate', function() {
    $('#result').text('finish');
    var foo = jQuery.sub();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box"></div>
<div id="box4" class="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a6KCr/

Comment: It is interesting to note how it is impossible to research this on google, because the `stack overflow` keywords are completely occupied by a certain programming site

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within the `jQuery.sub` method that you are calling repeatedly (on every triggereing of the `sortupdate` event). This seems pointless, especially since you are not doing anything with the resulting instance of jQuery.

Removing it fixes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/a6KCr/4/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
After the sorting, stack overflow will occur when run the jQuery.sub () at any time. http://jsfiddle.net/a6KCr/6/